# How can I get my double loop to get populated into the data frame?

Tags: r, loops

I'm trying to run a double loop for value k and i in the kknn model. I'm trying to store all my results into result, however, when running my script it only stores value k = 100 but all values of [i]. I am hoping to have k = 25, 50, 75, 100 while running all values [i] in each iteration of k.

```
result <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = (1000), ncol = 3))
colnames(result) <- c("k", "i", "fit")

for (f in seq(25, 100, 25))
{
  for (i in 1:nrow(credit_card_data))
  {
    model_knn <- kknn(V11~., credit_card_data[-i,], credit_card_data[i,], k = f, scale = TRUE)
    ##k <- f
    fit <- fitted.values(model_knn)
  result[i, 1] <- f
  result[i, 2] <- i
  result[i, 3] <- fit
  }
}
result
```

Comment: Please show a small reprouducible example

Comment: Unfortunately we can't reproduce this example entirely. The object `credit_card_data` is not provided. Can you add a subset of that data to your question?

Comment: In the line `result[i, 1] <- f` the content of `result[i, 1]` is overwritten with each new `f`. Every time you loop over a new `f` the result is always in `result[i, 1]`.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your example without data, but the below code seems to be doing what you are wanting.

```
result = data.frame(i = c(),
                j = c())

for (i in seq(25, 100, 25)) {
  for (j in 1:1000) {
    temp = data.frame(i = i,
                      j = j)
    result = rbind(result, temp)
  }
}
```

Which gives:

```
  i j
1 25 1
2 25 2
3 25 3
4 25 4
5 25 5
6 25 6
       i    j
3995 100  995
3996 100  996
3997 100  997
3998 100  998
3999 100  999
4000 100 1000
```